# React useState is not changing immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

- There are 4 states **credit, debit, total, and balance** and I want to perform some calculations.
- Formula: **balance = credit - debit + total** .
- I want to *store value of **balance*** in total using `useState`.
- Everything is working normally except the value of **total** which is not updating at the first submission of the form, it updates on the second submission of the form.
- `useEffect` is used in code but I don't understand how to update **total** on the very first submission.

```js
function Code() {
  const [credit, setCredit] = useState(0);
  const [debit, setDebit] = useState(0);
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  // Hard coded data
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([
    {
      credit: 1200,
      debit: 0,
      total: 1200,
    },
  ]);

  // performing credit & debit calculation and Adding Total into it
  useEffect(() => {
    setBalance(credit - debit + total);
  }, [credit, debit]);

  // Submit Button to save data in >>>records<<<
  const getInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //to Get Total Value after Submit
    setTotal(balance);
    setRecords([
      ...records,
      {
        credit: credit,
        debit: debit,
        total: total,
      },
    ]);

    // Again Providing Initial Values
    setCredit(0);
    setDebit(0);
    setBalance(0);
  };

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <label>Credit</label>
          <input
              type="number"
              value={credit}
              onChange={(e) => setCredit(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />

          <label>Debit</label>
          <input
              type="number"
              value={debit}
              onChange={(e) => setDebit(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button type="submit" onClick={getInfo}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
        {records.map((record) => (
            <p>
              credit:{record.credit}, debit:{record.debit} Total:{record.total}
            </p>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `setBalance` in the effect occurs ***after** all the enqueued state updates* from `getInfo`. It isn't clear at all what you want the code to actually accomplish otherwise I would have taken a stab at fix it. IMO I appears you want to carry forward the total from the previous record as the starting point to compute the next record's total (i.e. something like total = previousTotal + (credit - debit)).

Comment: The initial total should be initialized to 1200 with ```useState(1200) ``` instead of ```useState(0)```

Comment: @DrewReese yes i want exactly the same

Comment: everything is working fine but i only want to update total(useState) to work with it in future. @DrewReese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the balance effect to compute, the balance value can be derived from credits and debits. In fact, completely remove balance entirely, it appears to mostly duplicate `total`, and to be honest, makes the code rather confusing.

Create an effect hook to update the computed `total` when the `records` array is updated, i.e. "skim" the `total` from the last record. This "caches" the total so it can be the total to "update" from for the next record.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTotal(records[records.length -1]?.total ?? 0)
}, [records]);
```

[EDIT]

- [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) checks that an object is not nullish and continues accessing properties. `records[records.length -1]?.total` is more or less shorthand for `records[records.length -1] && records[records.length -1].total`.
- [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
  (`??`) is similar to logical OR (`||`), it returns the right-hand
  side operand when the left-had side operand is null or undefined. In the code above this is providing a fallback value for `total` state if the record has an undefined total for some reason.
- Overall the line `records[records.length -1]?.total ?? 0` should be equivalent to `(records[records.length -1] && records[records.length -1].total !== null && records[records.length -1].total !== undefined) ? records[records.length -1].total : 0`. Hopefully it is obvious how much less verbose code can be when using optional chaining and nullish coalescing operator.

[/EDIT]

Update `getInfo` to just add the new record, derive the balance/total from credits, debits, and total.

```
const getInfo = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setRecords((records) => [
    ...records,
    {
      credit,
      debit,
      total: credit - debit + total,
    }
  ]);

  setCredit(0);
  setDebit(0);
};
```

For good measure, start with all clean initial state and use an onMount effect to "load" the records. The first effect above will handle updating the total to be correct.

```
const [credit, setCredit] = useState(0);
const [debit, setDebit] = useState(0);
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setRecords([
    {
      credit: 1200,
      debit: 0,
      total: 1200
    }
  ]);
}, []);
```

[image: Edit react-usestate-is-not-changing-immediately]

Comment: did you explain this line of code to me  `useEffect(() => {
  setTotal(records[records.length -1]?.total ?? 0)
}, [records]);`.    **?** and **??** how these operators are working in this code

Comment: @USAMA Absolutely, amended my answer with a bit of explanation on the two.

Answer (score 0):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
> callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
> state, read about the updater argument below.

So `setTotal(balance)` will not update **total** value immediately.

**balance** should be used to update records.

Updated code snippet is just below.

```js
setRecords([
  ...records,
  {
    credit: credit,
    debit: debit,
    total: balance
  },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

the main point in :

```
setRecords([
  ...records,
  {
    credit,
    debit,
    total: credit - debit + total // for complete confidence
  }
]);
```

full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Code() {
  const [credit, setCredit] = useState(0);
  const [debit, setDebit] = useState(0);
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(1200); // Hard coded data too

  // Hard coded data
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([
    {
      credit: 1200,
      debit: 0,
      total: 1200
    }
  ]);

  // performing credit & debit calculation and Adding Total into it
  useEffect(() => {
    setBalance(credit - debit + total);
  }, [credit, debit, total]);

  // Submit Button to save data in >>>records<<<
  const getInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //to Get Total Value after Submit
    setTotal(balance);
    setRecords([
      ...records,
      {
        credit,
        debit,
        total: credit - debit + total // to enshure
      }
    ]);

    // Again Providing Initial Values
    setCredit(0);
    setDebit(0);
    setBalance(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label>Credit</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={credit}
          onChange={(e) => setCredit(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />

        <label>Debit</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={debit}
          onChange={(e) => setDebit(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit" onClick={getInfo}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      {records.map((record) => (
        <p>
          credit:{record.credit}, debit:{record.debit} Total:{record.total}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Code;
```